# XSL using apply templates and match instead of call template

Tags: xml, xslt, apply-templates

I am trying to make the transition from using call-template to using applay templates and match but i'm not getting any data displayed only what is between the volunteer tags.

When i use call template it works fine but it was suggested that i use applay-templates and match and not it doesn't work

Any ideas how to make this work? I can then applay it to all my stylesheets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:key name="volunteers-by-region" match="volunteer" use="region" />

    <xsl:template name="hoo" match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Registered Volunteers</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="volunteer.css" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Registered Volunteers</h1>
                <h3>Ordered by the username ascending</h3>
                <h3>Grouped by the region</h3>

                <xsl:for-each select="folktask/member[user/account/userlevel='2']">

                    <xsl:for-each select="volunteer[count(. | key('volunteers-by-region', region)[1]) = 1]">
                        <xsl:sort select="region" />

                        <xsl:for-each select="key('volunteers-by-region', region)">
                            <xsl:sort select="folktask/member/user/personal/name" />

                            <div class="userdiv">
                                <xsl:apply-templates/>

                                <!--<xsl:call-template name="member_userid">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="myid" select="../user/@id" />
                                </xsl:call-template>

                                <xsl:call-template name="member_name">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="myname" select="../user/personal/name" />
                                </xsl:call-template>-->

                            </div>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                    <div class="count"><h2>Total number of volunteers: <xsl:value-of select="count(/folktask/member/user/account/userlevel[text()=2])"/></h2></div>
                </xsl:if>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="folktask/member">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="user/@id"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="user/personal/name"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="user/@id">
        <div class="heading bold"><h2>USER ID: <xsl:value-of select="." /></h2></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="user/personal/name">
        <div class="small bold">NAME:</div> 
        <div class="large"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and my xml file

```
<folktask xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="folktask.xsd">
    <member>
        <user id="1">
            <personal>
                <name>Abbie Hunt</name>
                <sex>Female</sex>
                <address1>108 Access Road</address1>
                <address2></address2>
                <city>Wells</city>
                <county>Somerset</county>
                <postcode>BA5 8GH</postcode>
                <telephone>01528927616</telephone>
                <mobile>07085252492</mobile>
                <email>adrock@gmail.com</email>
            </personal>
            <account>
                <username>AdRock</username>
                <password>269eb625e2f0cf6fae9a29434c12a89f</password>
                <userlevel>4</userlevel>
                <signupdate>2010-03-26T09:23:50</signupdate>
            </account>
        </user>
        <volunteer id="1">
            <roles></roles>
            <region>South West</region>
        </volunteer>
    </member>
    <member>
        <user id="2">
            <personal>
                <name>Aidan Harris</name>
                <sex>Male</sex>
                <address1>103 Aiken Street</address1>
                <address2></address2>
                <city>Chichester</city>
                <county>Sussex</county>
                <postcode>PO19 4DS</postcode>
                <telephone>01905149894</telephone>
                <mobile>07784467941</mobile>
                <email>ambientexpert@yahoo.co.uk</email>
            </personal>
            <account>
                <username>AmbientExpert</username>
                <password>8e64214160e9dd14ae2a6d9f700004a6</password>
                <userlevel>2</userlevel>
                <signupdate>2010-03-26T09:23:50</signupdate>
            </account>
        </user>
        <volunteer id="2">
            <roles>Van Driver</roles>
            <region>South Central</region>
        </volunteer>
    </member>
    <member>
        <user id="3">
            <personal>
                <name>Skye Saunders</name>
                <sex>Female</sex>
                <address1>31 Anns Court</address1>
                <address2></address2>
                <city>Cirencester</city>
                <county>Gloucestershire</county>
                <postcode>GL7 1JG</postcode>
                <telephone>01958303514</telephone>
                <mobile>07260491667</mobile>
                <email>bigundecided@hotmail.co.uk</email>
            </personal>
            <account>
                <username>BigUndecided</username>
                <password>ea297847f80e046ca24a8621f4068594</password>
                <userlevel>2</userlevel>
                <signupdate>2010-03-26T09:23:50</signupdate>
            </account>
        </user>
        <volunteer id="3">
            <roles>Scaffold Erector</roles>
            <region>South West</region>
        </volunteer>
    </member>
</folktask>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue may be that when you do the **xsl:apply-templates** you are currently running within a **xsl:for-each** loop

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('volunteers-by-region', region)">
```

You are looping through volunteers, and so your current context will be a volunteer element. Thus, doing **xsl:apply-templates** will only match elements within the volunteer element, when what you want are details of the member element, which is the parent of the volunteer element. Therefore, you need to tell **xsl:apply-templates** to match the parent. Either of these should work

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=".." />
```

or

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*" />
```